# ¿Ceceo en "d" inicial de palabra?

Tags: pronunciación, ceceo-seseo

Es conocido que en español se dan los fenómenos de [ceceo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Cmi8vUAxBD6QBOs8iA) y [seseo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=IIUwJDU07D6XC2xEky).

Me ha pasado ya dos veces que, escuchando una canción, me da la sensación de que el cantante *cecea* al pronunciar una "d" inicial de palabra (concretamente la de la palabra "dime").
Las canciones en concreto son las siguientes. Enlazo al instante exacto en que se produce lo que yo oigo como ceceo:

- Antonio Orozco [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADZVekRpSHU&t=69) y [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADZVekRpSHU&t=126).
- Pablo López [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1owGTcbOpPM&t=112) y [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1owGTcbOpPM&t=142).

Para mis oídos, lo que están diciendo es "***z**ime*", en lugar de "dime".

¿Y esto a cuento de qué? Bueno, pues a cuento de que **no he encontrado un solo artículo o estudio que hable de "ceceo" al pronunciar "d" en inicio de palabra.** En lo que al ceceo respecta, la literatura sólo recoge (que yo haya visto) los casos de:

- *s -> c* en medio de palabra ("¿qué pasa?" -> "*¿qué paza?*");
- *d -> z* a final de palabra (Madrid -> *Madriz*).

Además, el ceceo clásico es un rasgo marcadamente geográfico, del sur de Andalucía. Pero resulta que Antonio Orozco es de Barcelona, con lo cual ignoro si esta forma de pronunciar es un deje andaluz que aquél intenta imitar, o si realmente está más extendida por la geografía española.

La cosa es que, salvo esos dos casos, no he escuchado a nadie más pronunciar así. Pero claro, ni me paso el día oyendo música de este estilo, ni vivo en zona ceceante (sí seseante; [la única al este de Andalucía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceceo#/media/File:Ceceo-seseo-distinci%C3%B3n_en_el_espa%C3%B1ol_de_Europa.png), aunque es un rasgo que se está perdiendo); así que puede ser falta de exposición.

Mi pregunta es: **¿alguien más ha encontrado esto en su entorno?** ¿Soy el único que oye "zime" (y no "dime") en los vídeos anteriores?
**¿Es posible que esté surgiendo un nuevo tipo de ceceo en España?**

Comment: Sobre la geografía y el ejemplo de Antonio Orozco, él nació en Barcelona de padres de Osuna (Sevilla), de acuerdo con Wikipedia, y su hablar puede tener mucho de andaluz. La mayoría de castellanohablantes en Cataluña con la edad de Antonio Orozco tienen raíces cercanas en otras partes, y su castellano suele ser una mezcla del dialecto de su familia y de los de las regiones de donde vienen las familias de su entorno. A eso hay que añadirle la gran proporción de andaluces en Cataluña, que hace que el castellano que se oye aquí tenga bastante de andaluz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ciertamente, en los ejemplos que das no se usa el fonema /d/ en la palabra *dime*, pero tampoco el fonema /θ/. El fonema que yo oigo es /ð/; es decir, el mismo que se usa en algunas palabras inglesas somo *this* o *that*. Este fonema tiene un punto de articulación intermedio entre /d/ y /θ/.

En mi opinión, no es más que una pronunciación un tanto afectada al cantar. Para hablar de un nuevo tipo de ceceo (tal vez necesitaríamos otro nombre, ya que, como digo, el fonema es distinto) necesitaríamos muestras habladas, no cantadas, y también un uso sistemático. En otros momentos de estas mismas canciones se usa claramente el fonema /d/ (en el primer ejemplo de Orozco, unos pocos segundos más tarde se usa un /d/ muy marcado en la palabra *dulce*).

Comment: Creo que Gorpik acierta al decir que esto es simplemente una afectación de la pronunciación. En cuanto al sonido en cuestión, a mí me suena a [ð] muy enfatizada. La realización de la /d/ intervocálica se considera convencionalmente fricativa pero en muchos casos es prácticamente aproximante. La desaparición dialectal de la *d* en palabras como *estado* (=*estao*) es el punto final de ese proceso de lenición. Lo mismo ocurre con las otras oclusivas sonoras (en Chile famosamente la palabra *huevada* se dice y se escribe popularmente *weá*).

Comment: El sonido al que me quiero referir es el que a veces se llama "z sonora". En inglés ver la relación entre ambos sonidos es fácil, porque los dos se escriben *th*. Es el mismo que en islandés se representa como ð. En castellano lo más parecido, en mi opinión, es el de la z seguida de consonante sonora (es decir, la de palabras como *juzgar* o *pazguato*). No sé si he usado el signo fonético correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Esto no tiene nada que ver con el ceseo. El ceseo es pronunciar los dos fonemas /s/ y /θ/ como [θ] sin distinción alguna. Lo que oyes aquí con estos cantantes no es [θ] sino una [ð̞] fricativa bastante alargada.

Todos los oclusivos sonoros en castellano se convierten en sonidos fricativos (y muchas veces aun aproximantes) en la mayoría de los contextos fonológicos. Leemos en el artículo de Wikipedia sobre [la fonología del español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol) como:

> - /b/, /d/, y /g/ son aproximantes ([β̞], [ð̞], [ɣ̞]; (de aquí en adelante representadas sin tachuelas) en **todas las posiciones** excepto después de pausa, después de consonante nasal, o, en el caso de /d/, después de consonante lateral; en estos contextos, son oclusivas sonoras.

No es por nada que se escribe *Madriz* tantas veces: se alarga el fricativo al final de la palabra.

[image: revista "Madriz"]

La verdad es que se manifiesta el fonema /d/ en una ancha variedad de alófonos, pero siendo meros alófonos, nadie va a confundir un fonema con otro simplemente al oír algún alófono.

Véase también [este inventario fonológico del castellano](http://phoible.org/inventories/view/553).